# JQuery simplemodal autoposition fails when focused on a textbox in webkit

Tags: jquery, webkit, position, focus, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal 1.4.4 and it has a strange behavior when I open the page on ipad.

The modal has autoPosition set to true. When it loads, it shows the modal centered successfully.

Inside the modal, I have textboxes for user and password. When I focused on the user textbox, the virtual keyboard opens, shrinking the viewport, but the modal continues on its position, and that's ok.

Actually, the problem is when I type something. A strange behavior occurs, the modal itself "moves" some pixels up. And then the textbox becomes hidden.

I found a common behavior, if I scroll the page up to see the texbox that was hidden, clear the texbox and then enter a new value, it moves up or down the "same" amount of pixels as that scroll I've made.

Summing up: It looks like it is autopositioning the modal every time I enter a value on the textbox, and the calculation for it is based on the scroll that I previously made:

- If I make a small scroll, and then enter a new value on the textbox, the popup moves a little.
- If I make a long scroll, and then enter a new value on the textbox, the popup moves too much far away.

If I disable the autoposition, it doesn't happen, but then the popup itself becomes invisible due to the css values that it has for default.

My options are:

- To disable the autoposition, set position:relative on popup-container and then change the popup margins properly to center it on the screen
- To find a possible workaround using autoposition.

I'm really willing to use the second approach, so I need help to investigate it further or to know if someone has had this kind of behavior and difficulty.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use "fixed" option:

$(element).modal({fixed: false}); Proof - https://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=80

My code

```
 $.modal(data, {
                        minWidth: 350,
                        maxWidth: 400,
                        maxHeight: 450,
                        autoResize: false,
                        overlayClose: false,
                        fixed: false,
                        opacity: 80,
                        onShow: runPopup
                    });
```